# Ember 2, Show message for an empty model instead of loading in hbs template, each or if

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I use very often in my code (and I don't know if I'm right to use it):

```
{{#each model.posts as |post|}}

  <div>post.title</div>

{{else}}

  <div>I'm loading the posts...</div>

{{/each}}
```

and until today everything OK.

**But now I don't know if the model.posts is empty or not.**

How to show an error instead of loading forever an empty array?

Answer (score 2):

A relationship on a model returns a `PromiseArray` which resolves to a `RecordArray`. On the `RecordArray` you can check [`isLoaded`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html#property_isLoaded). However you can't access this property, because the `PromiseArray` does not proxy this to the underlaying `RecordArray`. However the `PromiseArray` implements the [`PromiseProxyMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#property_isPending), which has `isPending` and `isSettled` available.

Checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6bf80fd82288a9293e3d5d2329d504bf?openFiles=adapters.application.js%2C) for a working solution.

Basically this is the working code:

```
{{#each model.posts}}

{{else}}
  {{#if model.posts.isPending}}
    <div>lade...</div>
  {{else}}
    <div>nix da :(</div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I like this but I see: `isLoaded` and `isLoading`. Why? I should use a computedProperty? Everytime? If I use the {{log}} this is what I get in my page: ```model.posts.isLoaded = undefined, model.posts.isLoading = undefined, model.posts.content.isLoaded = false, model.posts.content.isLoading = undefined, model.posts.content.isLoaded = true```

How to do?

Comment: Its `isLoaded`, sorry, `isLoading` is on the `model` itself and not relevant here. The output makes sense. `isLoaded` is falsy until the date is returned, that it gets `true`. So if you'r in the `else` part of an `each` and `isLoaded` is `true`, then you have no data.

Comment: Dear @Lux, this is not working. model.posts.isLoaded is always undefined. And so I'm stucked in loading even if there are no records. How to?

Comment: Maybe beacause I'm using Ember-data and my posts are hasMany post of Category model?

Comment: @JohnSam okay I was wrong. I've checked this and edited the answer.

Comment: It is not working again.... I always have `nix da :(` even in loading... and after some seconds posts appear...

Comment: If I use `{{log 'model.posts.isPending' model.posts.isPending}}` before `{{each...` in console I have `isPending true` and after 1ms `isPending false` also if it is loading data from server... Why?

Comment: Maybe is not working because I include the posts in my Category `show` json API?

Comment: Ok. I confirm. If I disable "include" in my Category `/show/:id` API json `model.posts.isPending` is true when Chrome start loading every post one by one. This is what I don't want. And I'm already in the first part of the `{{each`...

Comment: but then you can show loading spinners for each record ;)

Comment: Yes, but it's not what I asked. My API is with included models in json. How to?

Comment: But then the code in your question does not work either. The `I'm loading the posts...` text will only be shown for empty arrays, not while loading records. Now you have a new, totally different question: How to show a single loading message when the `id`s where included in the original response. But thats not the topic here.

Comment: Dear Lux, sorry, when I use this template (with `{{#if model.posts.isPending}}` or `isSettled` or `isFulfilled`) and now my promises are working good, I see a little "blink" betweeen `<div>nix da :(</div>` and `<div>lade...</div>`... Maybe `model.posts.isPending` is already immediately `true` then false, loading... and then first part of each is Ok. How can I avoid that "blink"?

Answer (score 1):

These two options come to my mind:

1. Use ember-promise-helpers, very easy to use directly in your template: https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers
2. As already stated, if you are working RecordArray check the `isLoaded` property.

Comment: Can you write an example of the second please?

Comment: Lux's answer has a full example

Comment: If what Is explained by Lux does not fit your use case, then you can just use point 1 Of my answer and go with the promise helper addon

Comment: Yes, I will try soon, but it seems strange to me that this isn't a native feature of Ember.

Comment: Ok. I tried. It's the same. If, for example, I try: `{{#if (await model.posts)}}` it says to me I'm waiting... forever! Because when data arrives is empty! And is the same of .isPending, .isFulfilled and so on... This is the problem. When I use included data in my response for `category` path.

Comment: I think this is not working because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035970/ember-2-strange-behaviour-with-ispending-issettled-isfulfilled-when-using-inc, shortly: I don't want many many HTTP requests. Just one for category (model) and one (non blocking, with loading message) for posts after the first one for model (category)...